# Is there any similar function to ST_MakeEnvelope from PostGIS in SqlServer?

Tags: postgis, sql-server

I need some function which make the same as ST_MakeEnvelope from PostGIS to use on a SqlServer DB. I need to get only some points from a geometry column to make my application run faster.

Comment: Have you tried STEnvelope https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stenvelope-geometry-data-type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using the following code

> DECLARE @g geometry;    SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON
>   ((-43.93606328159918 -19.78099695243067, -43.93606328159918
>   -19.781697344263762,-43.93457465559592 -19.781697344263762, -43.93457465559592 -19.78099695243067, -43.93606328159918 -19.78099695243067))', 0);
>
> SELECT [geometry] FROM [db].[TABLE] WHERE
>   @g.STOverlaps([geometry]) = 1;

the points of the polygon I got using calculateExtent from openlayers following this rule

> xmin ymax, xmin ymin, xmax ymin, xmax ymax, xmin ymax

I hope this help someone in the future